# How fix "BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default" error?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack, web3js

I want use **"web3"** and **"walletconnect/web3-provider"** package on vue & laravel 8. I install it by npm i --save web3 @walletconnect/web3-provider command and after that I add follows codes for import to vue.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Web3 from "web3";
import WalletConnect from "@walletconnect/client";
import QRCodeModal from "@walletconnect/qrcode-modal"
import WalletConnectProvider from "@walletconnect/web3-provider";

const connector = new WalletConnect({
    bridge: "https://bridge.walletconnect.org", // Required
    qrcodeModal: QRCodeModal,
});
window.walletConnector = connector;

//  Create WalletConnect Provider
const provider = new WalletConnectProvider({
    infuraId: "27e484dcd9e3efcfd25a83a78777cdf1",
});

//  Enable session (triggers QR Code modal)
await provider.enable();
```

But i get this error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 2:16-43 Module not found:
> Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
> '/var/www/tok/node_modules/cipher-base'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
> - install 'stream-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:   resolve.fallback: {
>   "stream": false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/keccak/lib/api/keccak.js 1:22-39 Module not
> found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
> '/var/www/tok/node_modules/keccak/lib/api'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
> - install 'stream-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:   resolve.fallback: {
>   "stream": false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/keccak/lib/api/shake.js 1:22-39 Module not
> found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
> '/var/www/tok/node_modules/keccak/lib/api'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
> - install 'stream-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:   resolve.fallback: {
>   "stream": false }
>
> webpack compiled with 3 errors

Apparently this error is related to Webpack configuration. How can I solve it? Someone can help me?

Comment: I have no idea about this, but as the message tells you, did you try installing `stream-browserify` as it recommends ? did you try anything ?

Comment: I install "stream-browserify" and add it to the web pack configuration in the form resol.fallback.stream: Requetime.resolve ("stream-browserify"). The problem was solved :) Thank you.

Comment: downgrading react-scripts to 4.0.3 worked for me. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70446839/react-js-with-web3-issue

Answer (score 5):

Run `npm i react-app-rewired`

Create config-overrides.js file and add this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = function override(config, env) {

    config.resolve.fallback = {
        url: require.resolve('url'),
        assert: require.resolve('assert'),
        crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
        http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
        https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
        os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
        buffer: require.resolve('buffer'),
        stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
    };
    config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser',
            Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
        }),
    );

    return config;
}
```

Install all the packages from config-overrides.js.

In package.json, replace the scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Comment: Anyone facing similar issues with the question can read more about this solution at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired

Comment: Hi there, thanks for that answer! Just to be sure about a potential typo in your answer, should the `eject` command not stay `react-scripts eject` as mentioned in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired ?

Answer (score 2):

Due to the removal of default polyfills in webpack5, you must install the following utilities:

```bash
yarn add buffer util stream-browserify assert stream-http url https-browserify os-browserify
```

OR

```bash
npm install buffer util stream-browserify assert stream-http url https-browserify os-browserify
```

Then, add the following code snippet to your webpack.config.js:

```js
resolve: {
 fallback: {
   fs: false,
   'stream': require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
   'buffer': require.resolve('buffer/'),
   'util': require.resolve('util/'),
   'assert': require.resolve('assert/'),
   'http': require.resolve('stream-http/'),
   'url': require.resolve('url/'),
   'https': require.resolve('https-browserify/'),
   'os': require.resolve('os-browserify/'),
 },
}
```

If you are using an application built on `create-react-app` locally, you must run `npm run eject` to be able to customize your webpack configuration.

Comment: Okay, so I don't use yarn. How do I do this in NPM?

Comment: npm install buffer util stream-browserify assert stream-http url https-browserify os-browserify

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by specifying the empty fallbacks like this:

```
fallback: { "http": false, "https": false, "stream": false, "tty": false, "zlib": false }
```

This goes in the `resolve` section in the webpack config:

```
{
        mode: isDevBuild ? 'development' : 'production',
        target: ['web', 'es5'],
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js'],

            /* polyfills used to be included, now they must be manually added. however, they will error out if not added */
            /* thus the :false fallbacks */
            fallback: { "http": false, "https": false, "stream": false, "tty": false, "zlib": false }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

If your error starts like this 'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' ...' installing `url-loader` will do the trick. Just install it using npm. `npm install --save-dev url-loader`