# React JS with Web3 issue

Tags: reactjs, web3-react

After created a ReactJS project. I installed Web3 to that project and just import Web3
But after imported, I got these error messages:

> Failed to compile.
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
> '/Users/tuan/Documents/projects/faucet-react/node_modules/cipher-base'
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
> - install 'stream-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "stream": false } assets by path static/js/*.js 6.09 MiB   asset static/js/bundle.js 6.08 MiB [emitted]
> (name: main) 1 related asset   asset
> static/js/node_modules_web-vitals_dist_web-vitals_js.chunk.js 6.89 KiB
> [emitted] 1 related asset asset index.html 1.67 KiB [emitted] asset
> asset-manifest.json 458 bytes [emitted] cached modules 5.9 MiB
> [cached] 899 modules runtime modules 31.5 KiB 17 modules

Are these issues from the react-script version?

Comment: I found the solution. It was the react-script version. So the version 5.0.0 was the issue and I downgraded it to 4.0.3 and it is working fine!!!

Comment: hello how did you do it? Im trying npm i react-scripts@4.0.3 but got a lot of errors post installation, app still broken

Comment: I did the same with this command line npm i react-scripts@4.0.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web3 Issue : React Application not compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70472965/web3-issue-react-application-not-compiling)